# Consuming WCF web service in Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I am not able to retrieve the result from the WCF web service. The result is always `null`.

Here is my Silverlight client code:

```
TTServiceClient client1 = new TTServiceClient();
            client1.GetUserNameCompleted += new EventHandler<GetUserNameCompletedEventArgs>(client1_GetUserNameCompleted);
            client1.GetUserNameAsync();

void client1_GetUserNameCompleted(object sender, GetUserNameCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtUserName.Text = e.Result;
        }
```

My web service implementation looks like:

```
public string GetUserName()
{ 
    return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString(); 
}
```

But I am able to get the result in wcf service.

Comment: You need to post more info regarding the web service and your configurations (ClientConfiguration as well as Web.Config).

Comment: public string GetUserName()
       {
           
           return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();

       }

Comment: i am getting the values here but not while consuming

Comment: What error do you get when trying to connect to the service?

Comment: i am not getting any error while consuming i am just getting null

Comment: @neo: any input on my answer below? what does `e.Error` say?

Comment: I am sorry for replying late. e.Error says Null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Silverlight webservice will not throw any exceptions regardless if the request was successful or not. In your callback you should, however, always check for errors the `eventargs e.Errors`, in your case something like:

```
void client1_GetUserNameCompleted(object sender, GetUserNameCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Error != null)
   {
       throw new Exception("Web service error: " + e.Error.Message);
   }
   else
   {
       txtUserName.Text = e.Result;
   }
}
```

Supposedly `e.Error` will tell you more about the problem.